What is Koheles' view of the Torah?
Koheles doesn't mention the special election of Israel, Maamad Har Sinai or Nevuah.
It does talk about God, right and wrong and reward and punishment.
Do any major Jewish thinkers entertain the possibility that Koheles' conception of the revelation is the conscience, which is universal, namely, that God reveals His will to us constantly via the conscience, instructing us regarding right and wrong and good and evil, and for which we're rewarded and punished accordingly?

ס֥וֹף דָּבָ֖ר הַכֹּ֣ל נִשְׁמָ֑ע אֶת־הָֽאֱלֹהִ֤ים יְרָא֙ וְאֶת־מִצְוֹתָ֣יו שְׁמ֔וֹר כִּי־זֶ֖ה כָּל־הָֽאָדָֽם:

@LaniedSofey That certainly seems to be the straightforward meaning of the verse. However, given the absence of anything more specific it can perhaps be interpreted to be referring to God's commands via the conscience.

"The Sages sought to suppress the book of Ecclesiastes... And why did they not suppress it? Because its beginning consists of matters of Torah... as it is written: “What profit has man of all his labor which he labors under the sun?” (Ecclesiastes 1:3), and the Sages of the school of Rabbi Yannai said: By inference: Under the sun is where man has no profit from his labor; however, before the sun, i.e., when engaged in the study of Torah, which preceded the sun, he does have profit. Its ending consists of matters of Torah, as it is written: (the verse that @LaniedSofey quoted). (Shabbos 30b)

Why would anyone interpret Koheles as being in opposition to the other books of the Bible? This question just sounds like wishful thinking.

There are several jumps there from what it doesn't say to what you're proposing it does.
The 70 bulls offered at that time are for the nations of the world; Sukkos has a universal theme. Thus, at face value, Koheles is addressed universally. (And therefore the name of G-d is Elokim.) The idea would be that anyone could come to Jerusalem and be given this teaching. If they ask "why should I consider it wrong to oppress the weak?"... well, if you're at the Temple in Jerusalem, you're going to hear a very theistic answer!
Now Chazal also interpret it in Jew-specific ways -- "the time to tear" is when Israel split into two kingdoms; many quotes are homiletically applied to Torah study.
